# "Datamining" from websites

Tags: python, shell

A friend of mine wants to get some data from certain webpages. He wants it in XML, because he will feed them to some mighty application.

That's not a problem, any scripting language can do this. The problem is, that the content is "hidden" and can only be seen, when user is logged in. Which means, in whatever language I'll use, I have to find a way to simulate a web browser - to store cookies (session id), because without it, I won't be able to get data from restricted sections of the website.

I don't wish I have to write my own "web browser", but I am not certain if I need one. Also I think, there must be a library for this. Any ideas?

**Yes, we asked them about API's, data dumps, etc. They don't want to cooperate.**

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: This would probably be better asked on Software Recs. As a matter of fact, [someone has asked a similar question already](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20082/python-library-for-complex-web-scraping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the Scrapy http://scrapy.org/ framework. It supports cookies, redirect, and almost anything you want to support for a nice crawling activity. Except Javascript.

If you need Javascript, have a look at phantomjs http://phantomjs.org/ .

Scrapy is in Python, but there are equivalent libraries for most languages out there. Go hunt them!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing HTML, there is also [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)
Try googling for 'web crowling' or 'web scraping' and see what fits you best.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to deal with JavaScript while web-scraping, you can use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) (python library) + [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (web browser without graphic rendering of the web page). It allows to simulate user's behavior on the website.

But if the only obstacle is handling login to the hidden part of the web site you can try to use **requests** python library for sending POST request with required headers data (username and password), receiving the cookies and then use GET request to scrape the data. **Session()** object will keep cookies for you in this case:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

login_form_data = {'username': 'user', 'password': 'pass123'}
req = session.post('http://anyweb.com/login.php', login_form_data)
req = session.get('http://anyweb.com/anypage.php')
response_data = req.text
```

Answer (score 1):

For ease of use, try Selenium.

Although it is slower compared to using headless browsers, the good thing is you don't need to use other libraries to enable Javascript since your script will simulate an actual human browsing a website. You can also check the behaviour of your script visually since it opens the website in your browser.

You can easily find boilerplate codes and tutorials about it too :)